# New Ubuntu Upgrade to 14.0.4.2 made some programs not running

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, wine, tor

about 2 days ago my automatic ubuntu update started to alert that there is problem with updates not being installed. So i changed my server and did it manually but it got failing to download at some point for many times, i finally realized some third party software is not being updated, i unchecked it and did it again, seemed ok, then i realized wine that was working prior to this error, is not working at all, i reinstalled it, did not work, did whatever i found in forums about wine not working, came at no solution, i did the upgrading to 14.0.4.2 with command line, it seems the upgrade was already in place. During this i needed Tor and Vidalia, after installing, vidalia happened to behave exactly as wine. before this update that came with error i had no problem as such. So any clue what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some new patches available today.  Try running Software Updater again.  After I installed the latest kernel and patches, wine started working again for me.  Perhaps it will help with your other issues too.

Comment: Worked somehow. I reinstalled wine after updating new kernel, using its recommended guide from [its webpage] (https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu). Had other problem though, it missed mfc42u.dll, had to copy this dll file manually to ~/.wine/system folder , then it started working